# How to get a foundary service whitelist IPs

Tags: service, cloud-foundry, whitelist

We have a GUI that manages Cloud Foundry, and there's a link that show an instance with IP white list external dependency (quite large)  How can I easily re-create this config as JSON, and recreate to diff Foundry env ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what is being presented in your GUI but it sounds like it might be the application security groups.  You might try running `cf security-groups` or `cf security-group <name>` to see if this information matches up with what's displayed in the GUI.

If that's what you want, you can use the following API calls to obtain the JSON data & recreate it in another environment.

1.) List all the security groups:  http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/1.40.0/security_groups/list_all_security_groups.html

2.) List security groups applied to all applications:  http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/1.40.0/security_group_running_defaults/return_the_security_groups_used_for_running_apps.html

3.) List security groups applied to all staging containers:  http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/1.40.0/security_group_staging_defaults/return_the_security_groups_used_for_staging.html

4.) Retrieve a particular security group:  http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/1.40.0/security_groups/retrieve_a_particular_security_group.html

And you can find more details about the API calls here:  http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/

You can also run the `cf` cli commands above with the `-v` flag to show the HTTP requests being made by the CLI to obtain the information that's displayed.

Hope that helps!